# Multiple Secure As400 connection in one application using ssl certificate at runtime - Java

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, truststore

I am trying to create multiple on-demand secure connections with different As400 instances. I made jdbc connections which depends on user input.

Now The problem is the certificates of those instances are also different.

I know to create a secure connection we set our certificates and password in System properties like - javax.net.ssl.trustStore and javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword. But this happens at startup only. We cannot change it again during lifetime of the application.
Is there any possible way to change the trusted certificates at runtime?

Comment: Why don't you put all the required (CA) certs in one truststore? It's designed to work that way.

Comment: I thought of that. But what if one of the certificates expires? What to do then. We have more than 20 different certificates

Comment: Delete the obsolete one and insert the new one. Or just delete old ones that are no longer needed, and just insert new ones that didn't exist before. 20 is no problem; the default JRE/lib/security/cacerts normally used for servers on the public net is about 100.